# Vue3: Warning on changing routes with transitions to route containing transitions

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In my App.vue I have declared

```
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
  <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <component :is="Component" />
  </transition>
</router-view>
```

to switch between routes like `$router.push({ name: 'ComponentName' })`. When I switch to another route, I get the following warning:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:38 [Vue warn]: Vue received a Component which was made a reactive object. This can lead to unnecessary performance overhead, and should be avoided by marking the component with `markRaw` or using `shallowRef` instead of `ref`. 
Component that was made reactive:  {name: "Step1_add", components: {…}, methods: {…}, data: ƒ, render: ƒ, …}components: {Multiselect: {…}}data: ƒ data()methods: {submitForm: ƒ}name: "Step1_add"render: ƒ render(_ctx, _cache, $props, $setup, $data, $options)__emits: null__file: "src/components/steps/Step1_add.vue"__hmrId: "db590442"__props: []__proto__: Object 
  at <Add onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< Proxy {updateView: ƒ, …} > > 
  at <BaseTransition mode="out-in" appear=false persisted=false  ... > 
  at <Transition name="fade" mode="out-in" > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

I have noticed, this happens only with routes, where I declared another transition within the route like

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <component
    :is="view"
    @previous-page-s1="$router.replace({ name: 'Home' })"
    @next-page-s1="updateView('Step2')"
    @previous-page-s2="updateView('Step1_add')"
    @next-page-s2="updateView('Step3')"
    @previous-page-s3="updateView('Step2')"
    @next-page-s3="updateView('Step4_add')"
    @previous-page-s4="updateView('Step3')"
    @next-page-s4="$router.replace({ name: 'Home' })"
  ></component>
</transition>
```

What exactly is causing this warning and how can I avoid it with keeping all transitions? I'd appreciate a hint. Thanks

Comment: How are you importing the component? The error message pretty much says what needs to be done, you either have to wrap your import with an arrow function such as `() => import('...')` or wrap the imported component with the `markRaw` function, e.g.: `markRaw(component.default)`.